# icCube - How can I modify the information that will be exported in Excel file

Tags: excel, modifier, iccube

This the OutPut of my Excel file :

[image]

I want to Change the date to be more comprehensible. Thanks for your Help

Comment: `more comprehensible` what does that mean exactly?

Comment: Ok, for this example , i want just 2014-08-07 , the date must be simple

Comment: Easy to do in Excel. No idea what iccube is.

Answer (score 0):

This is known [issue](http://issues.iccube.com/issue/ic3pub-238), will be part of next release.

As a workaround you can use [DateToString](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Java%20Functions.php) function in your measure.

---

DateToString function does not convert currently, will be done in the next release, measures to their values (see [issues](http://issues.iccube.com/issue/ic3pub-240)).

As a workaround you'll have to do this manually :

```
[Measures].[My Date].value
```

or

```
[Measures].[My Date].value->asValue()
```

The second is needed if you're using a special aggregation method (e.g. min/max/open/close ) and will need Java to be active in icCube ([doc](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx_integration/java_integration.php))

Comment: I added an image to explain for you about "DateToString"  , Thank you for your help.

Comment: use the MDX IDE to check the error, your expression is wrong